# Getting [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] even after adding the installing the certificates to the docker

Tags: python, docker, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I am getting SSL error when I am trying to build the container.
I have company.cert file which I've installed on the docker container still I am getting that error.

I was getting this error while using `requests` library and turns out I had to install the certificates inside docker container too.

My `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install whois

WORKDIR /account
COPY company.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /account/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /account/
```

error I am getting after I do the `docker-compose up --build`

```
Creating network "account-be_default" with the default driver
Building web
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.71MB
Step 1/11 : FROM python:3.9
 ---> 5b3b4504ff1f
Step 2/11 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3ab7ff8dcf36
Step 3/11 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e89f8643627c
Step 4/11 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install whois
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77189be8a39b
Step 5/11 : WORKDIR /account
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d4bc9c47ab3f
Step 6/11 : COPY company.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
 ---> 7ec13f5eab00
Step 7/11 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in e344730376b6
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container e344730376b6
 ---> a9f8dd0d0eac
Step 8/11 : COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /account/
 ---> 41050c53486a
Step 9/11 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 825d3a84efbf
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.1.2)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
Removing intermediate container 825d3a84efbf
 ---> dd02cef0099f
Step 10/11 : RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
 ---> Running in dfd537b70926
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/pipenv/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pipenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pipenv/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same corporate Secure Web Gateway (SWG) issue where the connection is signed by a non-standard CA. This was complicated by pip not passing CLI flags to subprocesses, so using CLI flags would work for simple pip installs, but fail if pip needed to build the module.

Fix was to add the SWG cert to a standard bundle (eg from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) and then tell pip to use the customised bundle via the PIP_CERT environment variable as per https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5502

```
ADD ../ssl/myCaCerts.pem /usr/local/share/myCaCerts.pem
ENV PIP_CERT=/usr/local/share/caCert.pem
RUN pip install <TheModule>
```